# Railsのモデルに共通の処理を与えたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User << ActibeRecord::Base

  json_column :data

end

class Post << ActibeRecord::Base

  json_column :info

end
```

このように、各モデルの対象のカラムを指定することで、保存前と値の参照の時に加工する処理を追加できるようにしたいのですがやり方がわかりません。

```
class ActibeRecord::Base
  before_save :before
  after_find :after

  private

  def before
    # json_columnで指定された値を文字列にキャスト
  end

  def after
    # json_columnで指定された値をJSON.parseする
  end
end
```

こんな感じのものを`raols_root/config/initializers/json_column.rb`に設置して動かすイメージです。
これであっていれば`json_column`で指定した値の取得方法さえわかれば実装できるような気がしてます。

それと、この`json_column`の名前はなんというのでしょうか?
調べ方がわからずに困っています。

サンプルソースや参考サイトなどを教えていただけるとうれしいです。
よろしくお願いします。

※ 今回はわかりやすいようにjsonを例にしましたが、実際に行いたい処理は違います。

Answer (score 2):

[class_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/classes/Class.html#method-i-class_attribute) はどうでしょうか。

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  class_attribute :json_column
  before_save :before

  private

  def before
    p [ self.class.json_column, self[json_column] ]
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.json_column = :data
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  self.json_column = :info
end

User.create(data: 'xxx')
Post.create(info: 'yyy')
```

Answer (score -1):

バリデーションの実行やデータベースへの保存などのタイミングをフックして処理を行いたい場合

Active Record コールバック
https://railsguides.jp/active_record_callbacks.html

---

モデルの値の変更を検出したい場合

Active Model Dirtyモジュール
https://railsguides.jp/active_model_basics.html#dirty%E3%83%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB